# Control node access on content type with field permissions

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

I'm straggling with a conflict for controlling permission access on node base and on field base.

- My use case is: I've a content type representing a learning project with a set of fields (Author, type of project, materials...) which should be visible only to a group of students. The value of one of the fields (module A, module B, module C ...) is characterizing the difficulty of the project and to which user it should be visible. On base of this field the node should be fully accessible or not for a specific role. If it's not accessible however there should appear a subset of the fields of the node, the same subset of fields appears also to a not authenticated users.
- I've defined the different field permissions for the roles, and then I was hoping that with Content Access or Simple Access while creating my content I could check to whom is visible. But as said in various tutorials using more than one access module could lead to conflicts and in fact what I can't do is for a specific node and a specific role to make visible all the fields, while for the other roles are visible only the subset of fields for that node.

What could be a good and less painful (hoping no coding) way to go?
Thanks in advance for any suggestion and help you can give me.

Comment: How much content has already been created?

Comment: Hy pokermoneyclips. I have more or less 100 nodes already created...I was also checking TAC ,  Pannels (but I don't want to replicate nodes) and Premium node.